# Yii CLinkPager hide First and Last

Tags: php, yii

When I call CLinkPager, it automatically create a paginator like:

```
<< First | < Previus | 1 | ... | 5 | Next > | Last >>
```

How can I disable to not show `First` and `Last` in pagination?

CLinkPager Code:

```
<?php $this->widget('CLinkPager', array('pages' => $pages)); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually cleaner to turn it off using CLinkPager options:

```
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array('pages' => $pages,
    'firstPageLabel'=>'',
    'lastpageLabel'=>'',
));
```

Comment: It doesn't 'hide' buttons. It shows them with 'empty value'. So if you will have specific css they will be shown any way.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide those buttons by CSS

```
ul.yiiPager .first, ul.yiiPager .last {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: The problem was that I used a custom class for pagination =) Thanks, I managed to solve with your tip.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use jquery to remove element, if only hiding using css, button space still there.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".first" ).remove();
    $( ".last" ).remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `d-none` class on css which contains `display:none` and put the class name for `prevPageCssClass`

```
        echo LinkPager::widget([
            'pagination' => $pages,
            'prevPageCssClass'=>'d-none',
            'nextPageCssClass'=>'d-none',

        ]);
```